# Get only one field from django forms in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have one form :

```
class FormLogin(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=150)
    name  = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

How can I put just email field in my template ?
I tried this :

```
{{ form.fields.email }}
```

But it returns `<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x00000000043BCEB8>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use:

```
{{ form.email }}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I have a filter added. Something like this `{{ form.email | crispy }}` throws me a `'BoundWidget' object has no attribute 'field'` error

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `fields`.
Use:

```
{{ form.email }}
```