# Django sub-Form not display label when rendered on template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

After reading over the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/), and working with Django forms for quite a while, it would seem pretty standard to me that `{{ form.as_p }}` in the template would render a Django form. However, my situation is a bit different.

I have 2 checkboxes in my form:

```
class FORM(forms.Form):

field_a = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, label =('FIELD-A'))
field_b= forms.BooleanField(initial=True, label=('FIELD-B'))
```

I pass the form object as most would from the view:

```
    context = {
        'FORM':FORM(),

}
return render_to_string(template, context)
```

I am trying to use basic 'if' logic to see if I should display one, or both of the fields. I know most would say 'Just name them two separate forms', but I would prefer to keep them as one form for organization purposes.

**THE PROBLEM**

```
        {% if BoolValue' %}
            <form action='' method='post'>
                 {{ FORM.field_a }}
            </form>
        {% endif %}
```

*This returns only the field*, and not the field label (so just a checkbox). Going off of the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) and other StackOverflow [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521634/get-only-one-field-from-django-forms-in-template), this should display the entire form, including the label, yet it doesn't.

These methods still work, however:

*METHOD 1*

```
            {% for field in FORM%}
        <div class="form">
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

*This will display both forms, with their respective labels, and field inputs (checkboxes)*

*METHOD 2*

```
{{ FORM.as_p }}
```

*The traditional way of rendering the entire form will display both fields and labels, it is virtually identical to Method 1 in style and formatting.*

**EDIT**
 *METHOD 3*

```
{{ FORM.field_a.label_tag }} {{ Form.field_a }}
```

*This will display the label and the form field. A possible work around, but I am looking for why {{ Form.field_a }} does not work on its own*

## So...

**Why can I not render that individual form with its respective label?** I am not looking for a work around so to speak, as I would like both fields to be under that one form. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ FORM.field_a }} {{FORM.field_a.label_tag}}`? It works?

Comment: Confirmed. The above method does work.

Comment: I'll put it as answer :D

Comment: This is the normal, documented behavior.  See the "Looping over the form's fields" part of the form docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields .  The rendered form field is just that - the field itself, not any of its supporting attributes like a label, help text or errors.  All of which are available via the documented attributes.

Comment: Thank you @PeterDeGlopper, I guess I did not figure that it was iterating over the form object when I called that sub-field. The link is excellent.

Comment: You don't actually have to iterate - you can access fields by name, as in your accepted answer, or by iterating over `form.fields` as in that link.  The point is that given a field object, either from iteration or from named access, you can use its attributes like `label_tag`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `{{ FORM.field_a }} {{FORM.field_a.label_tag}}`?

Comment: This is the best work-around. As @PeterDeGlopper commented above, this seems to be [normal behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) for Django when iterating over a form object.

Comment: this doesn't work however if the field is dynamic